# Why is unix timestamp appearing differently on local machine versus production server PHP: round(microtime(true) * 1000)

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I'm using a timestamp in a function and generating it in my local Wordpress Docker site like this (PHP):

`round(microtime(true) * 1000)`

Works as expected and gives me something like `1659069789179`.

However, the same code gives me something like `1.6590697862E+12` on my production Wordpress server.

Anybody have insight into why this happens and how I can get the current timestamp consistently across environments?

Comment: Looks like the same number to me, just in a different representation. Multiplying microtime() by 1000 gives you a timestamp in nano seconds. Do you need timestamps like that? Mostly, one-second resolution is good enough.

Comment: Both of those are numbers. If you want to display the value consistently then you can use something like [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). However you might also want to check if you have a 32 vs 64 bit OS/PHP build on each machine and try to match them.

Comment: @apokryfos is right. PHP has the predefined constant PHP_INT_MAX - the largest integer supported. 
For 32 bit systems it is 2147483647, and 9223372036854775807 in 64 bit systems. A value greater than this, will be stored as float, because it exceeds the limit of an integer.

Comment: @apokryfos I was thinking it was 32 bit vs 64, but both return 9223372036854775807

Comment: 9223372036854775807 definitely does not fit in 32 bits how are you checking this? It needs to be checked with exact same php binary that is also generating the above code (in your case that would probably be in a container)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting the timestamp (ms) to format consistently this way:

```
list($msec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
$time_milli = $sec.substr($msec, 2, 3);
echo $time_milli;
```